# Google Cloud Endpoints, works locally, not working when deployed

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

**UPDATE:**
When I try to set version 1 (I only have version) as the default version in Settings>App Engine> Version I get a weird error saying "The version could not be set as the default" Could this be whats causing the problem? Any ideas on how to fix?

**ORIGINAL POST:**
I have been developing a project with Google Cloud Endpoints. So far I have developed it all locally. I went to deploy it today and something isnt working. I can access the API and API explorer when on localhost. So `http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/myapi/v1/test` will work but when I deploy it, it isn't working. I get 'Note found' when I visit `http://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/myapi/v1/test`. The same is true for the api explorer, it works locally but then I get nothing when I try to use it on deployed URL.

The deploy seems successful:

```
 % appcfg.py update .                                                                                  
07:00 PM Application: struction-api; version: 1
07:00 PM Host: appengine.google.com
07:00 PM
Starting update of app: struction-api, version: 1
07:00 PM Getting current resource limits.
07:00 PM Scanning files on local disk.
07:00 PM Cloning 5 application files.
07:00 PM Uploading 2 files and blobs.
07:00 PM Uploaded 2 files and blobs
07:00 PM Compilation starting.
07:00 PM Compilation completed.
07:00 PM Starting deployment.
07:00 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
07:00 PM Deployment successful.
07:00 PM Checking if updated app version is serving.
07:00 PM Checking if Endpoints configuration has been updated.
07:00 PM Will check again in 1 seconds.
07:00 PM Checking if Endpoints configuration has been updated.
07:00 PM Will check again in 2 seconds.
07:00 PM Checking if Endpoints configuration has been updated.
07:00 PM Completed update of app: struction-api, version: 1
07:00 PM Uploading index definitions.
```

I also can't see any errors when I check logs or admin logs.

Here are the logs:
`Endpoints: https://1-dot-struction-api.appspot.com/_ah/api/structions@v1 Saved`

and the admin logs:
[image: admin-logs]

According to all the docs, this means it has been deployed with no errors.

Could the issue been in my app.yaml? Here it is:

```
application: my-app
version: 1
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1

handlers:
# Endpoints handler
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: myapi.APPLICATION

libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: latest
- name: endpoints
  version: 1.0
```

According to everything I have found, I am doing everything correctly but my APIs still won't load. I am using NDB if that could be a factor, but I can't even access APIs that don't have any data storage stuff going on.

Thanks in advance if anybody knows thats going on here, very frustrating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It did end up having to do with the version. For some reason the new Cloud Platform Admin console was throwing the error not allowing me to set the application as default.

I went the old app engine admin interface, found the versions links on the left bar and in here I was able to set my (only) version as the default. Then everything started to work.

Comment: Since you've solved your own issue, please [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as solved.

Comment: I have the same problem and I can't understand your solution, can you help me further?!